# Make a histogram of the number of times different characters appear

Tags: c

Just your standard C primer program. I'm trying to print out a histogram of all the different characters that a user inputs as a string.

```
#include <stdio.h>


#define LIMIT 255


main(){
int asciiArray[LIMIT], input, outer, inner;

while((input = getchar()) != EOF){
    asciiArray[input] = ++asciiArray[input];
    //printf("%d\n", asciiArray[input]);
}
for(outer = 0; outer <= LIMIT; outer++){
    if(asciiArray[outer] < 0){
        putchar(outer);
        printf("\t");
        for(inner = asciiArray[outer]; inner > 1; inner--)
            printf("*");
        printf("\n");       
    }
    else
        ;
}
```

}

These are the results when the user inputs "h":

```
h0
2
9
?
@
C
G
J
K
U
Z
a
b
h
j
l
n
q
}
�
�
�
�
�
�
�
�
�
�
�
�
�
�
�
�
�
�
�
�
�
�
�
�
�
�
�
�
```

Comment: Re: the statement `putchar(outer);`: remember that ASCII values 0 to 31 are control characters and don't correspond to a printable character.  Similarly, values above 127 are extended ASCII, and who knows what you're going to see there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For starters, you are not initializing `asciiArray`, thus it may contain everything.

Try `memset(asciiArray, 0, sizeof(asciiArray));` or `int asciiArray[LIMIT] = {0}`.

Also, you can simplify that increment in the while to: `asciiArray[input]++`.

The `for` looks fishy too (especially how **it accesses `asciiArray[255]`**). What's more, I don't see how `asciiArray[outer]` can be less than `0` Perhaps you meant `>` ?.

Comment: Instead of memset just initialize with `{ 0 }`

Comment: @Joe Mighty fine suggestion :-) Edited.

Comment: Needs to be done at initialization ;) `int asciiArray[LIMIT] = {0}, input, outer, inner;`

Comment: Merci Bocu! I was mostly making assumptions with the whole > reversal. I assumed that it automagically initialized nulls to a negative number. Thanks I learned a lot from what I thought was a stupid question!

Also, could you tell me how I could improve the for loop?

Answer (score 3):

LIMIT should probably be set to 256 and then the for loop should have

```
for(outer = 0; outer < LIMIT; outer++)
```

Otherwise you are going outside the array.

As others have mentioned, the array should be initialized.

Later in the if statement, it is also checking that the value is less than zero instead of greater than.
It should be:

```
if(asciiArray[outer] > 0)
```

and the second for statement is off by one (assuming you are trying to display one star for each instance of the character).  It should be:

```
for(inner = asciiArray[outer]; inner >= 1; inner--)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize your ascii array to 0;

```
i = 0;
while (i < LIMIT)
{
a[i] = 0;
i++;
}
```

Comment: That's not initialisation, strictly speaking :)

Comment: No it's "setting", they are languages where you don't have to and every free bytes that lefts are set to 0; And, sorry for my bad english, that's why i speak with simple words that are not allways understable.

Comment: Wait so an array in C, all the values need to be initialized to 0?